# Unable to get original object from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
account = Account.find(1)
customer = ThirdPartyAPI.retrieve("123456")
account.customers.import(customer)
```

And here's the import method:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account

   def self.import(customer)
      # I need to get the Account ID. 
      # Have tried `self.account.id`, but it throws this:
      # NoMethodError: undefined method `account'
   end
end
```

From within that `import` method, I'm trying to get the main account ID. As you can see in my code comment, when I try to call `self.account.id` it throws a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'account'` error.

My Account model has the association setup:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the customer to the account's array of customers? If so, you may want to do it like this:

```
account.customers << customer
```

You can't access `self.account.id` from the class method because you are not referring to a particular instance of the class `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

The `customer` object you got from third party API is not a persisted object in Customer. There is no id.

You can think it as a Hash with attributes of customer. Then all you need to do it to save it, and assign an `account_id` as `account` object to it.

```
def self.import(customer_attr, account)
  attr = customer_attr.merge account: account
  customer = create attr
end
```